# Pywin32 Outlook Restrict function stopped working

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I have been using the code snippet below to grab every email in a certain subfolder received within the last 3 hours and extract some business information from them before processing, and it has been working great for a week or so. However, yesterday for some reason I noticed it hasn't been working properly, and when I added a print statement to see what emails are sent to the process function I noticed its sending everything from march to the present date (over a 1000 emails).

```
        outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        api_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1).Folders['Some Folder']

        start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=3)

        # 05/01/2020 05:23 AM is this the right format?

        start = start.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

        messages = api_folder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start + "'")

        # This prints emails that shouldnt be here after Restrict()
        for msg in messages:
            print(f"{msg.Subject} - {msg.ReceivedTime}")
```

I'm pretty sure it probably is a very dumb mistake in the way Restrict is called or maybe on the time formatting but since I am new to programming I haven't been able to find the root cause of what is making the function misbehave.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although dates and times are typically stored with a `Date` format, the `Find` and `Restrict` methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the `strftime` (or `Format` in VBA) function. And make sure Outlook understands it:

```
api_folder.Items.Restrict("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" >= '9/15/2019 12:00 AM')
```

Note, you may configure the required filter in Outlook manually to get the string representation and use it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The below code in python, is working fine for me, Please don't include the **'seconds' restriction, only restrict to date(mm/dd/yyyy), hour and minute + mention AM/PM** for the mail (Ex: 12/22/2021 09:44 AM) and should provide datetime object in string(converted) format to apply restriction.

```
def read_mails(subject_line: str, start_datetime: datetime, end_datetime: datetime):
    """
    Read the outlook inbox and saves the attachments in the selected destination directory

    """
    print("\nReading messages..")

    # get outlook app
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.application")

    # getting path for saving attachments
    destination_path = ask_input("select folder to save")

    print("Checking Inbox...")
    inbox = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)

    restriction = (
        "[ReceivedTime] >= '"
        + start_datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
        + "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '"
        + end_datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
        + "'"
    )

    # reading restricted inbox messages
    retriving_messages = inbox.Items.Restrict(restriction)
    print("Restriction: ", restriction)

    for message in list(retriving_messages):
        if subject_line.lower() in message.subject.lower():
            save_attachments(destination_path, message)
        else:
            continue
```