# Python - Win32com - Restrict method using ReceivedTime not fetching emails

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

Code snippet with issue:

```
start_time = start_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %S')
end_time = end_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %S')
filtered_emails = emails.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + start_time + "' AND [ReceivedTime] <= '" + end_time +"'")
```

Observations:

- Tried both %S and %p options with same results
- Code was fetching the records based on the filter correctly until 30th Septemer 2023
- Code was unchanged and remained without any issues for about 3 months
- Noticed issue since 1st October 2023
- No emails are fetched if either of the dates are on or after 1st October.
- Consider the following 3 input cases, the code works correctly for case 1 but no emails are returned for case 2 and 3

Input case 1- start_time and end_time respectively: '20/09/2023 00:00 00' and '30/09/2023 23:59 59'

Input case 2- Input start_time and end_time respectively: '29/09/2023 00:00 00' and '01/10/2023 23:59 59'

Input case 3- Input start_time and end_time respectively: '02/10/2023 14:36 52' and '02/10/2023 15:06 52'

Tried suggestion from similar posts:

1. [Win32com outlook filter by date stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72089012/win32com-outlook-filter-by-date-stopped-working)
2. [Pywin32 Outlook Restrict function stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541881/pywin32-outlook-restrict-function-stopped-working)
3. [python win32com.client outlook application is not filtering received emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69440749/python-win32com-client-outlook-application-is-not-filtering-received-emails)

thank you for your feedback!

Comment: 1) Please read [mre] and insert a view of what `emails` looks like for recent months.
2) Could not find docs for `.Restrict`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.